# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'PersonConfig'. ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'PersonConfig'.ts(2322)
The expected type comes from this index signature.

```
interface Person {
    [Id: string]: PersonConfig
}

interface PersonConfig {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

const people: Person[] = [
    {
      "p1": {
          name: "abcd",
          age: 20
      }
    },
    {
      "p2": {
          name: "efgh",
          age: 78
      }
    }
];
```

Now I want to append some other string to keys of people i.e, ("p1" & "p2").

Expected Solution:

```
const suffix:string = "sub";

const people: Person[] = [
    {
      "p1" + suffix: {
          name: "abcd",
          age: 20
      }
    },
    {
      "p2" + suffix: {
          name: "efgh",
          age: 78
      }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const people: Person[] = [
    {
      ["p1" + suffix]: {
          name: "abcd",
          age: 20
      }
    },
    {
      ["p2" + suffix]: {
          name: "efgh",
          age: 78
      }
    }
];
```